# How to get User Details using Facebook connect in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal

I have the login for a Drupal site using Facebook connect, but the username is 11111111@facebook.

How can I fetch the information of a Facebook user to Drupal site?

Comment: Are you using the facebook connect module? http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect?

Answer (score 0):

Use [FB](http://drupal.org/project/fb) with [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel). Then it gives you a block with all the FB detials of the ogged in user.